# How would I re-implement dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

One of the exercises in Stroustrup's book reads as follows:

> Write a template `ptr_cast` that works like `dynamic_cast`, except that it throws `bad_cast` rather than returning 0.

The only solution I managed to come up with was to cheat by wrapping `dynamic_cast` proper:

```
template<typename Dst, typename Src>
Dst ptr_cast(Src* p) {
    Dst pt = dynamic_cast<Dst>(p);
    if (!pt)
        throw std::bad_cast();
    return pt;
}

class B {
public:
    virtual ~B();
};

B::~B() {}

class D : public B {};
class C {};

int main() {
    B* pb = new D;
    D* pd = ptr_cast<D*>(pb);  // passes
    C* pc = ptr_cast<C*>(pb);  // throws as planned

    return 0;
}
```

However, I have a lingering suspicion that it's not what the author meant. Does anyone have a better idea? The item is marked with one star, which means it must be something really obvious.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is a fundamental part of C++. There are no other alternatives to it, and I can't think of any possible way to interpret this question other than what you wrote, above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost exactly matches one from the [polymorphic_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/polymorphic_cast.hpp) in boost:

```
//  Runtime checked polymorphic downcasts and crosscasts.
//  Suggested in The C++ Programming Language, 3rd Ed, Bjarne Stroustrup,
//  section 15.8 exercise 1, page 425.

template <class Target, class Source>
inline Target polymorphic_cast(Source* x)
{
    Target tmp = dynamic_cast<Target>(x);
    if ( tmp == 0 ) boost::throw_exception( std::bad_cast() );
    return tmp;
}
```

So it is probably a good one.

Comment: Thanks for answering my original question before some guy edited it into a duplicate. One day I will definitely understand why they do such things, but not today.